# Odoo set Default Customer In Odoo Point Of Sale Module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

as we know odoo has point of sale module and we can set customer in that module

[image: Customer POS Img]

How to set Customer by default is One of all customer.

in example, by Default customer is "Joko"

I'm sure about  Customer named "Joko" exists

Someone could please help me?

For Your information I'm using odoo 10.

I would be apreciate for every correction and respons in this question.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do this by setting your static customer id as a selected from js file of POS. This means at the time of loading a session by default customer is selected.